# How to use a GetType and pass it to a function

Tags: vb.net

why doesn't passing a datatype of an object to a function work? and how do you get around it?

```
Dim MyObj as new CustomObj
Dim t As Type = MyObj.GetType
Call My_Fuction(Of t)
```

I'm saving serializable objects to file, then open them up later on, and then the code needs to find the UI based on the object datatype, so it can populate the UI from the object

```
Private Function My_Fuction(Of t As Base_Object)() As UserControl   
Dim UI_Type As Type = GetType(UI_Common_Panel(Of t))   
For Each Object_type As Type In Project_Solution.GetTypes()    
For Each Itype As Type In Object_type.GetInterfaces()
        If Itype Is UI_Type Then Return DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(Object_type), UI_Common_Panel(Of t))    
Next   
Next   
Return Nothing  
End Function
```

Comment: Why are you tagging VB.NET code as C#?

Comment: I've tagged both, because i will accept an answer in either languages

Comment: I think you are confused how generic constraints work

Comment: yes, hence why i asked the question...

Comment: What is the definition of `My_Function`?

Comment: The `Of T` syntax is used in the method definition to constrain what types are allowed.  If that were done properly, your call to your non-function as `Call MyMethod(myobj)`

Comment: Ammend your post to show My_Fuction please.

Comment: Call MyMethod(myobj) will not work for my case. sounds like its not possible.

Comment: Why not flip all the cards and share *what* you are trying to do?  If you dont know what a generic constraint is or what it does, maybe it is not part of the solution

Comment: I'm saving serializable objects to file, then open them up later on, and then the code needs to find the UI based on the object datatype, so it can populate the UI from the object

Comment: it works if i define the datatype, but need it to work dynamically

Comment: function added.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to give a good answer because you have all custom classes in your question. If the problem you are trying to solve is to create a new control based on the object's `Type`, here is a way to do that using built-in controls:

```
Function GetControl(o As Object) As Control
  If o.GetType Is GetType(Boolean) Then
    Return New CheckBox With {.Checked = DirectCast(o, Boolean)}
  ElseIf o.GetType Is GetType(Date) Then
    Return New DateTimePicker With {.Value = DirectCast(o, Date)}
  ElseIf o.GetType Is GetType(String) Then
    Return New TextBox With {.Text = DirectCast(o, String)}
  Else
    Return New TextBox With {.Text = o.ToString}
  End If
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim c As Control = GetControl("Hello, world!")
  Me.Controls.Add(c)
  c.Visible = True

  Dim c2 As Control = GetControl(#05/04/2017#)
  Me.Controls.Add(c2)
  c2.Visible = True
  c2.Top = 100
End Sub
```